# in javascript, how does a new object function extend a prototype function of same name?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype-programming

when creating an object I wish to extend the functionality of an existent prototype function with a new function. the new function needs to call the original prototype function to perform, but they are apparently in the same namespace.

```
Obj = function(i,newFn) {
   this.i = i;
   if( newFn ) this.fn = newFn;
}
Obj.prototype.fn = function(a) { return a+this.i; }

o1 = new Obj1( 3, function(a) { if( a<0 ) return 0; return ORIGINAL.fn(a) } );
```

if ORIGINAL is `this.fn` then `o1.fn` becomes non-terminating recursive

how do I reference `Obj.prototype.fn()` from within `o1.fn()`?

---

answer, as per @PeterOlsen,

```
o1 = new Obj1( 3, function(a) { return Obj.prototype.fn.call(this,a) } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get there, you just might have to go a little farther than you expected. Try something like

```
Obj = function(i,newFn) {
   this.i = i;
   if( newFn ) this.fn = newFn;
}
Obj.prototype.fn = function(a) { return a+this.i; }

o1 = new Obj( 3, function(a) { if( a<0 ) return 0; return this.constructor.prototype.fn.apply(this, arguments) } );
```

In your closure, get the prototype for the constructor that was used to make this object, and then use `.apply()` to invoke the instance method you want using `this` and the arguments you passed in.

Or like Peter Olson said, instead of `this.constructor.prototype.fn` you can use `Obj.prototype.fn`, but you still need to use either `.call()` or `.apply()`, to make sure that you execute the method in the right scope, otherwise `this` wont point to what you think it should.

Comment: think `Obj.prototype.fn.call(this,a)` is simplest

Answer (score 2):

> how do I reference Obj.prototype.fn() from within o1.fn()?

Quite simply, reference it with `Obj.prototype.fn`.